# App Inventor on Mac with Genymotion

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to use App Inventor on Mac with Genymotion.

When I start the aistarter, I received the following

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ /Applications/AppInventor/commands-for-Appinventor/aiStarter ; exit;
Bottle server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8004/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Shutdown...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 129, in <module>
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 2389, in run
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 2086, in run
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 144, in make_server
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 408, in __init__
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 48, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/BaseHTTPServer", line 108, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 419, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/socket", line 224, in meth
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
Killed adb
No matching processes belonging to you were found
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Killed emulator
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a web server running on that port already:

```
setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/BaseHTTPServer", line 108, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 419, in server_bind
line 224, in meth
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
    socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Figure out what's already running on that port, and turn it off. You can only have one service listening on a given port at any time.

It's possible that you have two copies of it running.  If so, kill one of them.  You can see what ports are currently listening in the terminal with:

```
sudo lsof  -P -i -n | grep -i listen
```

Comment: @FawziAlhammadi please accept the answer if it solved your problem.